# Weird glitches on css hover over link

Tags: html, css, menu, hover

I am trying to make a navigation menu in which the image after the link in HTML (or before the link as seen, because I am reversing the order) is changed. Here is my code:

```
<div class="submenu">
    <a href="cat4.php" class="text" id="cat4">Category 4</a>
    <a href="cat4.php"><img src="image/submenu/cat4_transp.png" id="cat4" /></a>
    <a href="cat3.php" class="text" id="cat3">Category 3</a>
    <a href="cat3.php"><img src="image/submenu/cat3_transp.png" id="cat3" /></a>
    <a href="cat2.php" class="text" id="cat2">Category 2</a>
    <a href="cat2.php"><img src="image/submenu/cat2_transp.png" id="cat2" /></a>
    <a href="cat1.php" class="text" id="cat1">Category 1</a>
    <a href="cat1.php"><img src="image/submenu/cat1_transp.png" id="cat1"  /></a>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
div.submenu {
    width: 100%;
    direction: rtl;
    unicode-bidi: isolate;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 3.5px solid #AB0809;
    font: 20px verdana;
}
div.submenu a { color: black;  display: inline-block; }
div.submenu a.text { padding: 10px; padding-bottom: 2px; position: relative; bottom: 10px; }
img#cat1:hover, a#cat1:hover ~ a img#cat1 { content:url("../image/submenu/cat1_painted.png"); }
img#cat2:hover, a#cat2:hover ~ a img#cat2 { content:url("../image/submenu/cat2_painted.png"); }
img#cat3:hover, a#cat3:hover ~ a img#cat3 { content:url("../image/submenu/cat3_painted.png"); }
img#cat4:hover, a#cat4:hover ~ a img#cat4 { content:url("../image/submenu/cat4_painted.png"); }
```

The images in question are not big - 30x40 px and about 3KB each. Here are the few glitches I experience in a video format:

[Glitch 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDTUqEZWV-I)

[Glitch 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yD4NUCXmrK4)

The first one happens when I run the site on localhost / XAMPP (you can see the glitch happen with the third picture, it kind of moves the whole row), and the second one happens when I upload the site on a free hosting (the image disappears for a second).

I am totally puzzled and I hope you can help me. I am using the latest version of Chrome / Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly specifying the img size? It seems that the browser is removing one image and then inserting the other, which changes the content flow. If it's explicit that a given element is a given width, it should mitigate that.

Answer (score 2):

I found out the solution to both problems and I am posting it here for anyone needing it.

Almost all of the glitches, except the one where the image disappears for a second, were gone after I replaced the <img> tags with <div> tags, to which I set a background using CSS. This also gave me a wider browser-support (including Firefox).

The problem with the disappearing image I solved by preloading the images needed (I set a dummy div on the top of the page and put all of the images as a background). This way, the images needed were already loaded and did not need to be loaded again, hence the delay.